# GRASS init error when adding GRASS as Plugin in QGIS 3.18.2

Tags: qgis, qgis-plugins, error, windows, qgis-grass-plugin

When I add GRASS from a list of Plugins, I receive an error:

> GRASS init error: GRASS was not found in 'C:/PROGRA~1/QGIS
> 3.18/apps/grass/grass78' (GISBASE), provider and plugin will not work.

Although the Plugin has been installed, when opening the GRASS drop-down menu, Open mapset etc. is greyed out.

I received the same error after installing the stable version 3.16.6.

I have so far tried to uninstall and reinstall various versions and I'm unable to get this going. Windows Version 10.0.19042 Build 19042.

Comment: If you are referring to the GRASS Tools being grayed out you need to open a mapset first, right clicking on it in the QGIS browser works.  If you don't have any mapsets you can open GRASS itself (I get to mine via the program list under OsGeo4W) and in the startup form create one there and then open that.  If you just want to use GRASS tools in QGIS you need to start QGIS Desktop with GRASS which in my case is in the same start folder.